# Is on premises IIS deployment supported by Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, iis-10

I've developed a .NET6 application, and need to install it on an on-premises IIS server, via Azure DevOps.

I've found these [yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/iisweb-app-management-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines) [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/iisweb-app-deployment-on-machine-group-v0) that look promising, but it says it's only for classic pipelines:

> This task is supported on classic release pipelines only.
> Use the classic designer to add and configure this task in a classic release pipeline.
> See the following Inputs section for details on the inputs that this task supports.

Is this scenario no longer supported on non-classic pipelines?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't find pre-built tasks which can do this for you, you should be able to roll your own script steps and run the pipeline on a self-hosted pipeline agent which has access to your on-prem IIS server.